Is posible to use Java 21, spring boot 3.x.x and old version of mongodb?
I created an api rest using java 21 and spring boot 3.3.5, and it needs to connect to remote mongodb. The version of mongo in the server is 4.2 (I think).
The problem is that, when I make a query, it says:
Server at xxxxxxxx reports wire version 5, but this version of driver requires at least 6 (MongoDB 3.6).
Is there a way to change the driver version?
Thank you in advance!

Here is some related info: Spring Data MongoDB -Requirements and Java Driver and MongoDB Compatbility.
